# Can I use the words constitutes and construe interchangeably?

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

Additional information:

I've heard these two words a lot of times and in different kinds of using and came up with the conclusion that these two words pretty close in terms of usage.

There's the [video](https://www.ted.com/talks/sam_harris_science_can_show_what_s_right/transcript?language=en#t-36000) that includes these two terms:

> 1 What ***constitutes*** a good life?
>
> 2  And if we have ***misconstrued*** the relationship between biological complexity and the possibilities of experience
>
> 3 Now, many of you might worry that the notion of well-being is truly undefined, and seemingly perpetually open to be ***re-construed***
>
> 4 There is clearly a range of materials that ***constitute*** healthy food

Questions:

> 1) Can I use the words constitutes and construe interchangeably.

- In case if I can use them interchangeably sometimes then when I can do it and when I can't?

> 2) Can I use these terms interchangeably in the #1 and #4?
>
> 3) Is it right expression: '**How to construe our life of itself**'?

Comment: They are absolutely different words. What made you suppose that they can be interchangeable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*X and Y constitute Z* means X and Y together make a Z, it's synonymous with *to be a part of*.

*Construe* is synonymous with *interpret* or *define given information X and Y*.

*Constitute* is concerned with the physical makeup of something, whereas *construe* is concerned with the meaning or interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, let's look up the words in the dictionaries.

- [**constitute**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/constitute) - to be or be considered as something; to form or make something.
- [**construe**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/construe) - to understand the meaning, especially of other people's actions and statements, in a particular way *(construe sth as sth)*; to understand (an action, event, remark, etc.) in a particular way; to interpret the meaning of (something).

---

1. **What constitutes a good life?** - What elements form a good life.
2. **And if we have misconstrued the relationship between biological complexity and the possibilities of experience** - if we have misunderstood (misinterpreted)
3. **Now, many of you might worry that the notion of well-being is truly undefined, and seemingly perpetually open to be re-construed** - be open to understanding or interpreting in a particular way.
4. **There is clearly a range of materials that constitute healthy food** - That make food healthy or add up to the food for it to be healthy.